# showing something using jquery while typing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, input

i wanted to show an image, only when the person starts typing into the text field.

i.e.

```
$('#type').keyup(function(){
//show the images
    });
```

html

```
<input type="text" name="type" id="type">

<div id="showimage"></div>
```

image

```
showimage.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#showimage').show();`?

Comment: @gateway do you get the image details fromn a ajax call or so ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jquery:

```
$('#type').keyup(function(){
   $('#image').show();
});
```

html:

```
<img id="image" src="showimage.jpg" style="display: none"/>
```

Comment: In case I want to dismiss the image if I delete all the text in the form, how to do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: @LuckyLuke You can use [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for hiding. See also [this SOq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518891/i-want-to-hide-fields-if-its-value-is-empty-and-image-src-also-in-html-using-jav) for similar examples.