# I want to hide Fields if its value is empty and image src also in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to hide fields in html if fields are empty and the image src also. using java script. please suggest

```
<div id="pagewrapper" >
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="column-half" style="width:500px">
            <div class="containerdiv" >

                <form:label path="file4Desc" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
                </form:label>
                <form:input path="file4Desc" value="${agreement.file4Desc}" 
                    style="width:300px"/>
                <font color="red"><form:errors path="file4Desc" /></font>           
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column-half" style="width:13%">         
            <div class="containerdiv">
                <form:label path="filename3" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
                </form:label>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/viewDownload3/${agreement.agreementId}.htm">
                    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/download3.gif" 
                                border="0"
                                title="Download this document"/>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: checking if the value of a field is null (empty)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244565/jquery-checking-if-the-value-of-a-field-is-null-empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : You can make use of `.filter()` and hide input if value is empty.

```
$(function(){
 $('.containerdiv input').filter(function(){
   return $(this).val().trim()=='';
 }).hide();
});
```

**[API Document for filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

**EDIT** - As OP want to hide both input and image if input value is empty, please see below updated solution

```
$(function(){
     $('.containerdiv input').each(function(){
       if($(this).val().trim()=='')
       {
          //hide parent div and next div having image
          var $parentDiv = $(this).closest('.column-half');
          $parentDiv.next('.column-half').hide();
          $parentDiv.hide();
        }
     });
  });
```

Comment: working fine for values ...thank you... but i want to do for this also                                                          <form:label path="filename" type="text" value="" maxlength="50" > <a    
      href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/viewDownload/${agreement.agreementId}.htm">
      <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/download3.gif" 
         border="0"
         title="Download this document"/></a><span style="color:red"></span>  
   </form:label>

Comment: you mean when label is empty then hide it or image is not there then hide it? please clarify.

Comment: i want to do for both... because image's description is available in fields...for fields its working fine... but the download image button still visible..i want ti hide that image also

Comment: so you want to hide both `div` with `class="containerdiv"` having input and image, right?

Comment: yes...if it is empty value.... ..i want to hide img src as well as field if they are empty

Comment: it means ...if field 1 is empty...it is hiding by using your script...but the image also be hide ... how can i hide imag src also if its content is empty

Comment: In your html code I can see `</div>` after closing first `<div class="containerdiv" >`. Is that right?

Comment: i have altered my code in question..please check it...then you will get an idea

Comment: i got it...thank you..i used "column-half"... so now am getting it.... thank you bro.... u are very helpful to me.... thank you

Comment: can we use this for <td> and <tr> also? for them how to write script?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 $('.containerdiv input').each(function(){
   if($(this).val().trim()=='')
     $(this).hide();
 })
});
```